# Ajax calls controller action with empty model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

When clicking on the "Update Name" button, the `UpdateDetails` action is called but the `Customer` model parameter is null for all properties.  Why is this?

**Controller:**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Customer customer = GetCustomer(id);

        return View(customer);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult UpdateDetails(Customer customer)
    {
        UpdateCustomer(customer);

        return PartialView("CustomerUpdateResult", true);
    }
}
```

**View extract:**

```
@model MvcTest.Models.Customer

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateDetails", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "CustomerUpdateResultDiv" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(cust => cust.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Update Name" />
}

<div id="CustomerUpdateResultDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Check the `ModelState.IsValid` flag. If false, there is an error collection that will tell you what is wrong, and you should return the model back to the view so that validation messages can be rendered.

Comment: check this under network tab in chrome/firefox(firebug) and see what are all the post parameter passed?

Comment: What do you mean that parameter is empty? It is null or maybe Id attribute is 0?

Comment: The code in the question works fine. May be you have some other thing in your project which is not here, is giving you trouble.

Comment: Maybe you have custom model binders?

Comment: @Yevgeniy: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  All the properties of the model are null.

Comment: I copied your code and dropped in my sample mvc project and ran it. IT works just FINE.

Comment: Even name? Or do you mean that all properties are null except name?

Comment: Yes, the name is also null.

Comment: The only problem in your code that i can see is that you do not provide id for your model. To resolve it add @Html.HiddenFor(cust => cust.Id) to your Ajax form. In all other aspects code is fine. Maybe you have some custom model binders which break binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code (in question) should work fine without any problem, assuming you do not have any other code which hijacks your click event and do something else.

But you will be only getting the name property value as you have only that in the form. So all  other properties will be null. What you can do is either include more properties in the form or read the customer object again and set only the updated property values before saving.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateDetails", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                   UpdateTargetId = "CustomerUpdateResultDiv" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(cust => cust.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c=>c.CustomerID)
    <input type="submit" value="Update Name" />
}
```

And in the HttpPost action, Get the customer object using the CustomerID and update relevant property values.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult UpdateDetails(Customer customer)
{
    var existingCustomer = GetCustomer(id);
    if(existingCustomer!=null)
    {
      existingCustomer.Name=customer.Name;
      UpdateCustomer(existingCustomer);
      return PartialView("CustomerUpdateResult", true);
    }
    return PartialView("CustomerNotFound", true);
}
```